# throw new ResourceNotFoundError(id) for id n that's not exist

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, express, error-handling

I'm building a small Full Stack system (typescript , express , NodeJs)  , and in one of the routes the user can ask for a movie based on a chosen theatre , here's the specific service:

```
async function getMoviesByTheatreId(theatreId : number) : Promise<MovieModel[]> {

    // SQL:
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM movies where theatreId = ?;'

    // Call dal:
    const movies = await dal.execute(sql ,[theatreId]);

    // Return:
    return movies;
}
```

*clarification*
there are two tables in the MYSQL database - theatres , and movies. They share a foreign key that reference the "theatreId" column in the theatres table. The foreign key is the one in the movies table.

Now , there is a chance that the user will send some theatreId that is not exist , in that case , I want to throw new ResourceNotFoundError. However , there's also a chance that the theatreId does exist , but there just aren't any movies matching this theatre. In that case , I don't want to throw that error.
I also want it to be good in terms of performances , sine checking the database with multiple queries can slow down the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if a theatre with the provided `theatreId` exists in the theatres table before querying the movies table. Then, you can query movies.

Here is example code:

```js
async function getMoviesByTheatreId(theatreId : number) : Promise<MovieModel[]> {

    const theatreSql = 'SELECT * FROM theatres WHERE theatreId = ?';
    const theatre = await dal.execute(theatreSql, [theatreId]);

    if (theatre.length === 0) {
        // throw new ResourceNotFoundError('Theatre not found');
    }

    // SQL to retrieve movies with provided theatreId:
    const moviesSql = 'SELECT * FROM movies WHERE theatreId = ?;'

    // Call dal:
    const movies = await dal.execute(moviesSql ,[theatreId]);

    // Return:
    return movies;
}
```

Comment: Ok so I should have mention that I did thought about it... But isn't it two queries are a bit to much?

Comment: you are executing single select query on primary key column so there will be no performance problem.